# How can I remove version 0.9.7 of sqlalchemy and install 0.7.8 instead?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, sqlalchemy

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to run snoopy_auth which is a part of the snoopy-ng application I downloaded and installed from their GitHub.

When running, I get an error that is documented on snoopy-ng's GitHub page, which says that it works using version 0.7.8.

How can I downgrade sqlalchemy to 0.7.8?

The error looks like:

snoopy_auth -l
[+] Available drone accounts:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/snoopy_auth", line 103, in 
    drones = auth_.manage_drone_account("foo", "list")
  File "/usr/bin/snoopy_auth", line 29, in manage_drone_account
    self.db.create(self.drone_tbl_def )
  File "", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 106, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/interfaces.py", line 859, in create
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError

Comment: "Downgrade to a two year old version"? Really? What's next for them, requiring Internet Explorer 5.0 to view their site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get passed this error I just simply ran the command:

sudo easy_install "SQLAlchemy==0.7.8"

The virtual environments do seem like the preferred method though, so hopefully I don't run into any additional problems from downgrading system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

As always with version conflicts, you should use [virtual environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html). Install whatever versions you need without breaking the systemwide packages.